# Global variables use inside the class instance JavaScript

Tags: javascript, testing

I have a class declared and exported in one js file. Inside this file my class instance can use global variable. I import this class to the tests file and there I face a problem that the variable is not defined.

this is my class

```
export class GuessingGame {
    setRange(min, max) {
        this.min = min
        this.max = max
    }
    guess() {
        if(this.min + 1 === number) {
            return this.min + 1
        } else if(this.max - 1 === number) {
            return this.max - 1
        } else {
        return Math.round((this.max - this.min) / 2 + this.min)
        }
    }
    lower() {
        if(this.guess() > number) {
            this.max = this.guess()
        }
    }
    greater() {
        if(this.guess() < number) {
            this.min = this.guess()
        }
    }
}
```

And if I declare var number inside the file with this class - the class instance can use it without any errors. But!

This is the test file, where it should use the global variable const number. But it gives me error  ReferenceError: number is not defined

```
import { GuessingGame } from './rolling-scopes-guessing-game.js';
import chai from 'chai';
import sinonChai from'sinon-chai';

global.expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('GuessingGame', () => {
describe('#guess', () => {
it('should guess number 409 with max value 4048', () => {
    const number = 409;
    const game = new GuessingGame();
    game.setRange(0, 4048)

    let result = game.guess();
    game.lower();
    result = game.guess();
    game.lower();
    result = game.guess();
    game.lower();
    result = game.guess();
    game.greater();
    result = game.guess();
    game.greater();
    result = game.guess();
    game.lower();
    result = game.guess();
    game.lower();
    result = game.guess();
    game.greater();
    result = game.guess();
    game.greater();
    result = game.guess();
    game.greater();
    result = game.guess();
    game.lower();
    result = game.guess();

    expect(result).to.equal(number);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: `GuessingGame` doesn't have a constructor? Is this on purpose? - Why don't you pass the number into the methods as they're called rather than relying on a global variable?

Comment: Declaring `const number` in the test file doesn't make that variable visible to `GuessingGame`. The scope in JS is *static* - determined at the time of declaration. You are treating it as *dynamic* - looked up at the time of invocation. It's simply incompatible. If you want a class to use some data, then that should be encapsulated in the class. It's part of the core principles of OOP. Classes carry with them *state* and you seem to want `number` to be part of the state of `GuessingGame`. So, declare it as a field. Or accept it as parameter if it's not part of the state.

Comment: what @VLAZ said. or you need to export from your test and import in your class file.

Comment: Is it your intention that `number` can change WHILE your `new GuessingGame()` instance is running? If not, just pass `number` via the constructor and use it as the `state` of your `game`. Or you can `export const mynumber = 400` from the main code and `import mynumber from ...` in your GuessingGame code.

Comment: The tests should read like documentation.  Your tests don't adequately describe how `GuessingGame` is supposed to work.  For example: if the GuessingGame is the trusted holder of the answer, then why isn't `guess` implemented as `return number`?  Or if the holder of the answer is the _caller_, then why doesn't `guess` just return the next guess -- why does it compare to `number` at all? Shouldn't that be the game show host's responsibility to know if the guess was right? (i.e. the caller should know what the answer is? and the GuessingGame is actually AI for a _player_ of a guessing game?)

Comment: Thanks for your responses. It was a task and the requirements are fixed. Therefore there is no constructor in the class. There tests are made by examination. By the way I have done the getter method inside the class to retrieve the number, and call it inside each 'it' block

Answer (score 0):

Your `number` global sounds very much like a `static` field:

```js
class GuessingGame {
    static number = 1234;
    
    setRange(min, max) {
        this.min = min
        this.max = max
    }
    guess() {
        if(this.min + 1 === number) {
            return this.min + 1
        } else if(this.max - 1 === number) {
            return this.max - 1
        } else {
        return Math.round((this.max - this.min) / 2 + this.min)
        }
    }
    lower() {
        if(this.guess() > number) {
            this.max = this.guess()
        }
    }
    greater() {
        if(this.guess() < number) {
            this.min = this.guess()
        }
    }
}

console.log(GuessingGame.number);
```

You can set `GuessingGame` from wherever you need. If you want it to be constant, you can define it as

```
    static get number() {
        return 1234;
    }
```